# $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\left(1+4\sin^4 x\right)\mathrm{d}x$ and the golden ratio

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, golden-ratio

We already know that, for any real number $t$ such that $t\geq-1$,

> $$
> \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \left(1+t \sin^2 x\right) \mathrm{d}x = \pi \ln \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{1+t}}{2} \right).
> $$

Prove that

> $$
> \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \left(1+4\sin^4 x\right) \mathrm{d}x = \pi \ln \left( \frac{\varphi+\sqrt{\varphi}}{2} \right)
> $$ 
>   where $\displaystyle \varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the golden ratio.

Comment: $1+4\sin^4x~=~(1-2i\sin^2x)(1+2i\sin^2x),\qquad\ln(ab)=\ln a+\ln b,\qquad\Re(\pm2i)>-1$.

Comment: @Lucian Bravo! What about $$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \left(1+t\sin^4 x\right) \mathrm{d}x ?
$$

Comment: As long as $t>0$, the same principle applies. For $-1<t<0$, it's even easier.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Looks like a great candidate for differentiating under the integral sign and a Weierstrass substitution.

Comment: @David H Yes, this was the standard way, but Lucian found out the trick!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $\quad1+t^2\sin^4x~=~(1-ti\sin^2x)\cdot(1+ti\sin^2x),\qquad\log(ab)=\log a+\log b,\quad$ and

$\Re(\pm~ti)>-1$.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{1 + 4\sin^{4}\pars{x}}\,\dd x
     =\pi\ln\pars{\varphi + \root{\varphi} \over 2}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&
> \partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{1 + \mu\sin^{4}\pars{x}}\,\dd x
> =\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sin^{4}\pars{x} \over 1 + \mu\sin^{4}\pars{x}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&={\pi \over 2\mu} -{1 \over \mu}\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
> {\dd x \over 1 + \mu\sin^{4}\pars{x}}}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}%
{\dd x \over 1 + \mu\sin^{4}\pars{x}}}
=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\csc^{4}\pars{x} \over \csc^{4}\pars{x} + \mu}\,\dd x
=\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}%
{\cot^{2}\pars{x} + 1  \over \bracks{\cot^{2}\pars{x} + 1}^{2}+ \mu}
\,\csc^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x}^{\ds{\cot\pars{x} \equiv t}}
\\[3mm]&=-\int_{\infty}^{0}{t^{2} + 1 \over \pars{t^{2} + 1}^{2} + \mu}\,\dd t
=\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1 + \root{\mu}\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\Re\bracks{{1 \over \root{1 + \root{\mu}{\ic}}}
\int_{0}^{\infty/\root{1 + \root{\mu}{\ic}}}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1}}
={\pi \over 2}\,\Re\pars{{1 \over \root{1 + \root{\mu}{\ic}}}}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{%
> \large\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{1 + 4\sin^{4}\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
> ={\pi \over 2}\,\Re\int_{0}^{4}\overbrace{%
> {1 \over \mu}\pars{1 - {1 \over \root{1 + \root{\mu}\ic}}}\,\dd\mu}
> ^{\ds{t \equiv \root{1 + \root{\mu}\ic}}}
> \\[3mm]&=2\pi\,\Re\int_{1}^{\root{1 + 2\,\ic}}{\dd t \over 1 + t}
> =\color{#66f}{\large 2\pi\,\Re\ln\pars{1 + \root{1 + 2\ic} \over 2}}
> \approx 1.1565078476153109133
> \end{align}

It agrees with the OP proposed answer
$\color{#000}{\large\quad\ds{\pi\,\ln\pars{\varphi + \root{\varphi} \over 2}}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's put it with real numbers.

We have

> $$
> \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \left(1+t\sin^4 x\right) \mathrm{d}x 
> = \pi \ln \left( \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{ 1 + \sqrt{1+t} } 
> \left( \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1+t} } + \sqrt{2} \right) \right), \quad t \geq -1.
> $$